# How to concatenate the name of a product with the name of its attributes after "woocommerce_thankyou" hook fires?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

```
$order_items = $order->get_items();

foreach ($order_items as $item_key => $item) {
 $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product Object

 if( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    $variation_names = array();

    if( $attributes ){
        foreach ( $attributes as $key => $value) {
            $variation_key =  end(explode('-', $key));
            $variation_names[] = ucfirst($variation_key) .' : '. $value;
        }
    }
    echo implode( '<br>', $variation_names );
 }
}
```

**The output of this code is as follows:**

After echo:

> %da%86%d8%b1%d8%a8%db%8c

and Incompatible with Persian language

**I need the end result to be something like this:**

> "product Name , color:red, size:85"
> .
> .
> .
> .
> .
> .
> .
> .
> .
> .

**Thanks to all the friends;**

**This is my new solution and it has been tested and it works:**

**Note**:attributes **$value label** added:

```
//اضافه کردن نام ویژگی به اسم محصول
//Add attribute label name to product name

if( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
        
$s ='';
$s1 = '';
foreach ($product->get_attributes() as $taxonomy => $attribute_obj ) {

 // Get the attribute label
 $attribute_label_name = wc_attribute_label($taxonomy);

 //convert to array 
 $attribute_arr = json_decode(json_encode($attribute_obj),true);
 $term_name      = get_term_by( 'slug', $attribute_arr, $taxonomy)->name;

 $s = $s . $s1 .$attribute_label_name.':'.$term_name;
 $s1 = ', ';

}

$name = $name . '(' .$s. ')';
echo '<p>' . $name. '</p>';


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wc_attribute_label()` to get the proper label name of the attribute and you can use `get_title()` to get the product title. try the below code.

```
function display_attributes_and_name( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id); //<--check this line
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($order_items as $item_key => $item) {
        $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product Object
        if( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ){
            $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            $variation_names = array();
            if( $attributes ){
                foreach ( $attributes as $key => $value) {
                    $variation_key =  end(explode('-', $key));
                    $variation_names[] = wc_attribute_label( $variation_key ) .' : '. $value;
                }
            }
            echo $product->get_title().', '.implode( ',', $variation_names );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'display_attributes_and_name', 10, 1 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Great solution...

Comment: Thanks; how to echo name? $value echo slug!

Comment: Problem recognizing Persian fonts: how to convert "%d8%a8%d9%84%d9%87" to "بله"?

Comment: تست متغییر1, شماره رنگ : 212,فاقد چربی : %d8%a8%d9%84%d9%87,رنگ : abi-

Answer (score 2):

What @Bhautik said

Plus

> *"Incompatible with Persian language"*

To me, it looks like it's been encoded (by your browser perhaps!), so in order to `decode` it, we could use `urldecode` function, like so:

```php
$test = '%da%86%d8%b1%d8%a8%db%8c';

$decode_test = urldecode($test);

echo $decode_test;
```

Which will output this:

```
چربی
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks; The code works properly.